# Logarithmic growth and integrability

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, intuition

I was helping a graduate student with a problem, and I realized that I didn't have a good *intuitive* explanation for the following phenomenon:

$$
\int_e^\infty \frac{dx}{x\ln^p(x)}<\infty \quad \forall p>1
$$

Obviously the result follows by integration with a $u=\ln(x)$ substitution.  However, I found it difficult to contrast this with the fact that $\ln^p(x)$ grows slower than any positive power of $x$, which "intuitively" suggests that the logarithmic factor won't improve the integrability of $1/x$ by itself.  Can anyone think of an intuitive (i.e. non-rigorous, "formal", whatever) way to explain this?

Comment: Is there an "intuitive way" for which the harmonic series is divergent? We may say "re-grouping of terms", i.e. Cauchy's condensation test. In a continuous context, it is just the use of a substitution, like $x=e^{t}$, in this case. We cannot always rely on intuition only, some mathematical facts are beyond it.

Comment: So, I guess you're saying that the substitution _is_ the intuition?  I might be able to buy that, I'll have to think about it.

Comment: Re-phrasing, I'd say there is no really "intuitive" way for understanding that $$\sum_{n\geq 100}\frac{1}{n\log(n)\log\log(n)}$$ is a divergent series, while $$\sum_{n\geq 100}\frac{1}{n\log(n)\left(\log\log(n)\right)^2}$$ is a convergent one. The given problem is just some sort of continuous analogue.

Comment: I haven't really considered this specific case, but I've always thought of $\frac{1}{x}$ as "just barely" not integrable, just like the harmonic series just barely diverges. If you want something even more disturbing, note that you can replace $\ln^p(x)$ with $\ln(x)\ln{\ln^p{x}}$, which is much smaller, and get a convergent integral. I haven't looked at baby Rudin in a long time, but I seem to recall him going out of his way to show that whether or not a series diverges is not really intuitive or predictable in any sense. I would guess integrals aren't much different.

Comment: My intuition  also says that $1/x$ is just barely not integrable, but then this says that $1/x\ln(x)$ might be integrable, but it isn't.

Comment: @icurays1 Yes, that was Rudin's point. There is no boundary above which a series diverges and below which it converges. It's more complicated than that.